# In ConcurrentHashMap's transfer method, I don't understand the meaning of these two conditions "i >= n" and "i + n >= nextn"

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

In the transfer method,the condition for judging the termination of the expansion (or the helping transfer threads finish) is `if (i < 0 || i >= n || i + n >= nextn) {`. I know `i < 0` this condition means that all bins have been allocated, but I don't understand the meaning of other two conditions:  `i >= n` and `i + n >= nextn`

Is `i >= n` considering a data overflow?(-2147483648 - 1 = 2147483647);

Is `i + n >= nextn` the same as `i >= n`?(I don't think so)

```
private final void transfer(Node<K,V>[] tab, Node<K,V>[] nextTab) {
        int n = tab.length, stride;
        //...
        int nextn = nextTab.length;
        ForwardingNode<K,V> fwd = new ForwardingNode<K,V>(nextTab);
        boolean advance = true;
        boolean finishing = false; // to ensure sweep before committing nextTab
        for (int i = 0, bound = 0;;) {
            Node<K,V> f; int fh;
            while (advance) {
                int nextIndex, nextBound;
                if (--i >= bound || finishing)
                    advance = false;
                else if ((nextIndex = transferIndex) <= 0) {
                    i = -1;
                    advance = false;
                }
                else if (U.compareAndSwapInt
                         (this, TRANSFERINDEX, nextIndex,
                          nextBound = (nextIndex > stride ?
                                       nextIndex - stride : 0))) {
                    bound = nextBound;
                    i = nextIndex - 1;
                    advance = false;
                }
            }
            if (i < 0 || i >= n || i + n >= nextn) {
                int sc;
                if (finishing) {
                    nextTable = null;
                    table = nextTab;
                    sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1);
                    return;
                }
                if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc = sizeCtl, sc - 1)) {
                    if ((sc - 2) != resizeStamp(n) << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT)
                        return;
                    finishing = advance = true;
                    i = n; // recheck before commit
                }
            }
            //...
}
```

Comment: Also what is this line doing?:  `int n = tab.length, stride;` Ironically following thru a Rust implementation and hitting similar questions myself.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQFWmGaFBjk&list=PLqbS7AVVErFj824-6QgnK_Za1187rNfnl @4:05:02

Comment: Doh.. was assigning 2 int vars n and stride.. and assigning tab.length to n. I bet Jon would be able to answer this question!

Comment: Jon also gives quite a good view from 10,000ft overview at the outset of the second video of how the algorithm works. May be worth a look at that;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=018GXMjfdqg&list=PLqbS7AVVErFj824-6QgnK_Za1187rNfnl&index=2

Comment: Thank you, I'll watch it when I get a VPN because I'm in China and can't watch YouTube:)

Comment: Do you have access to Twitter? jonhoo is the Twitter handle of Jon Gjengset who did this. https://twitter.com/jonhoo https://github.com/jonhoo Perhaps you could ask him via Twitter?

Comment: Another related oddity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651473/java-concurrent-hashmap-inittable-why-the-try-block

Comment: i have been looking at Jon's code here: https://github.com/jonhoo/flurry/blob/master/src/map.rs -  It looks to me as if n and nextn represent lengths of tables.. the nextn is used during resizing. So I suspect the Java code is going to be similar.

Comment: i am not sure if I understand your comment either. From Jons videos, my understanding is Java runs a hashing algorithm to determine the buckets into which things get inserted into. Items will then get added to the buckets as linked lists.. But if the number grows too large it switches to a Binary Tree (he didn't implement that part originally). Also when a resizing occurs other threads collaborate in the resizing so the time to complete the resize is reduced.

Comment: There is also something in there that takes into account a sort of block move of contiguous nodes (stride), and then number of CPUs is factored into the operators. Beyond that it's a bit out of my realm of expertise. Would probably have to sit thru it again to totally grasp it. If I have interpreted things correctly  n is the number from current iteration before resize, nextn is what it is going to be after the resize

Comment: (edited) ```n``` means that the capacity of the current table, and ```nextn``` means that twice the capacity of the current table at expansion time. So this condition ```i + n >= nextn``` is equal to ```i+n>=2n```. It's the same condition as the previous one(```i>=n```), isn't it? One more thing, if the condition ```i + n >= nextn``` can be executed, it must be that the previous two conditions are not true, so when will these two conditions(```0<=i<n``` and ```i + n >= nextn```) are true?

Comment: (Sorry for my poor English) My understanding is the same as yours, but what I don't understand now is the meaning of these two conditions ```i >= n``` and ```i + n >= nextn``` in the transfer method. Maybe only Doug Lea can answer it :(

Comment: What I also found very confusing is the for loop with the while (advance).. Two nested loops.. Initially I thought, why not a while (true) with a break and only have one. advance flag to me looked like a bad smell https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java But If you evaluate false first time. don't repeat yourself.

Comment: Have been continuing to go thru Jon's third video.. And he does some debugging and says something that coincides with what you said.. When the tables resize.. it's for the next power of 2.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z4fZkmlvrs (around 1:45:40)

Comment: I agree with you,maybe we can use a ```while (true)``` with a ```break``` here.

Comment: @RobertHou The question is how can we get Doug Lea to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

logically, it's a piece of dead code, i think it might be boundary dection during coding/deubging.

From the view of math, if i >= n, then

1. int overflow: impossible. because max resizing threshold is 1<<29，the maximum value of n is 1<<29
2. i become larger than n: impossible. beacuse i = nextIndex-1, while nextIndex = transferIndex, and transferIndex=nextIndex-stride

   if i>=n, then transferIndex need to be updated to larger value(doubled) by another thread.
   which means a new resizing happens while current resizing has not completed!

   it's definitely impossible

```
while (advance) {
  int nextIndex, nextBound;
  if (--i >= bound || finishing)
      advance = false;
  else if ((nextIndex = transferIndex) <= 0) { //here is the only chance to update nextIndex
      i = -1;
      advance = false;
  }
  else if (U.compareAndSwapInt
           (this, TRANSFERINDEX, nextIndex,
            nextBound = (nextIndex > stride ?
                         nextIndex - stride : 0))) {
      bound = nextBound;
      i = nextIndex - 1;
      advance = false;
  }
}
```

one might doubt the updated sequence of volatile variables, such as nextTable/table/sizeCtl, also impossible.

because at the end of resizing, they got updated as belows:

```java
//see the method transfer
if (finishing) {
   nextTable = null;
   table = nextTab;
   sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1);
   return;
}
```

And all the entering of transfer strictly check table/nextTable/sizeCtl and transferIndex.

again, no way to leak partially updates to transfer.

and so i+n >= nextn