# Java Concurrent Hashmap initTable() Why the try/finally block?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I have been looking at the following code (sourced from [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java))'

```
/**
 * Initializes table, using the size recorded in sizeCtl.
 */
private final Node<K,V>[] initTable() {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; int sc;
    while ((tab = table) == null || tab.length == 0) {
        if ((sc = sizeCtl) < 0)
            Thread.yield(); // lost initialization race; just spin
        else if (U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, -1)) {
            try {
                if ((tab = table) == null || tab.length == 0) {
                    int n = (sc > 0) ? sc : DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Node<K,V>[] nt = (Node<K,V>[])new Node<?,?>[n];
                    table = tab = nt;
                    sc = n - (n >>> 2);
                }
            } finally {
                sizeCtl = sc;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Can someone explain why there is a need for the try block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unchecked exceptions and errors exist as a concept. If you call `.put()` on a ConcurrentHashMap, and you're real tight on memory, that map may try to make an array, and that call may fail with an OutOfMemoryError. Code will still continue (at the catch block that catches this, perhaps), and the references to that map still exist. It would be a bit shite if, after that happens, the map crashes and is completely invalidated because sizeCtl has a broken value.

The point is that finally block, which restores the `sizeCtl` value. This is used for various things, notable including managing which thread gets access. If it didn't, any other put calls would spin forever.

The relevance of this (as in, how often does a throwable occur here, vs. removing the 'try' and the 'finally' and just ending with `sizeCtl = sc;` without the additional overhead of try/finally) is low, but if it is relevant, it is quite relevant.

Comment: Odd.. I had posted that possibility here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=018GXMjfdqg&list=PLqbS7AVVErFj824-6QgnK_Za1187rNfnl&index=2 So my hunch aligned to yours.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of mutex - and a double-check lock.

Firstly

```
if ((sc = sizeCtl) < 0)
    Thread.yield(); // lost initialization race; just spin
```

checks the `sizeCtl` mutex.  If it's less than zero, someone else has grabbed it, so we just wait for a bit.

If it's zero (or more), chances are we'd obtain the lock.  So a Compare-And-Swap is performed:

```
if (U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, -1)
```

This is an atomic operation - if another thread grabbed it between the first and second check, the `if` would not be taken.

If the CAS is successful, then the method becomes reponsible for releasing the mutex.  Therefore, a `try-finally` is used to ensure that the mutex is released (`sizeCtl` reset to its original value) irrespective of whether an exception occurs (e.g. out of memory assigning the new Node - or if there is a unique restriction applicable to the map) or not.

Comment: How can this be correct because the yield occurs outside the try?

Comment: Look upon it like wanting to go into a really small shop.  It can only accomodate one person.  So you walk to the door and take a peek in.  If you see someone's in there already, rather than wait, you go off and do something else for a bit (the 'yield').  

If you see the shop is empty, you go for the handle - but someone else might beat you to it - hence the CAS.

Does that make sense?

Comment: The `try-finally` is only necessary once the method is committed to accessing the resource.  Akin to closing the door after you exit the shop, even if the owner throws you out ungracefully ;)

Comment: For those looking for a decent book on Java Multithreading, I recommend "Concurrent Programming in Java" by Doug Lea.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Concurrent-Programming-Java%C2%99-Principles-Patterns/dp/0201310090