# ConcurrentHashMap - Can we get rid of i >= n from transfer()?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, java-memory-model

Related to :
[In ConcurrentHashMap's transfer method, I don't understand the meaning of these two conditions "i >= n" and "i + n >= nextn"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63597067/7134737)

I am looking into the transfer() method in [j.u.c.ConcurrentHashMap](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java).

Doesn't it make sense to just get rid of [i >= n || i + n >= nextn](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/88b4e3b8539c2beb29ad92bd74b300002c2ef84b/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2465) from the [transfer()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/88b4e3b8539c2beb29ad92bd74b300002c2ef84b/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2426) method ?

```
  for (int i = 0, bound = 0;;) {
        Node<K,V> f; int fh;
        while (advance) {
            int nextIndex, nextBound;
            if (--i >= bound || finishing) // always decreasing
                advance = false;
            else if ((nextIndex = transferIndex) <= 0) {
                i = -1; // obviously less than n
                advance = false;
            }
            else if (U.compareAndSetInt
                     (this, TRANSFERINDEX, nextIndex,
                      nextBound = (nextIndex > stride ?
                                   nextIndex - stride : 0))) {
                bound = nextBound;
                i = nextIndex - 1; // will be guaranteed to be less than n
                advance = false;
            }
        }
        if (i < 0 || i >= n || i + n >= nextn) { // why keep any thing other than i < 0
```

Given that `i` is a local variable I see no mathematical way it can exceed `n` (old table len).

Also, the [question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67656878/7134737) also says that its dead code.

Am I missing something about the JMM that needs to check this weird condition?

Answer (score 1):

It can, though:

> ```
> while (advance) {
>  int nextIndex, nextBound;
>  if (--i >= bound || finishing)
>    advance = false;
>  else if ((nextIndex = transferIndex) <= 0) { // !!!! LINE 1
>    i = -1;
>    advance = false;
>  }
>  else if (U.compareAndSetInt
>           (this, TRANSFERINDEX, nextIndex,
>            nextBound = (nextIndex > stride ?
>                         nextIndex - stride : 0))) {
>     bound = nextBound;
>     i = nextIndex - 1;
>     advance = false;
>   }
> }
>
> if (i < 0 || i >= n || i + n >= nextn) {
> ```

This code is highly non-idiomatic; it is written in a style somewhat common in older kernel/low-level C code style and not at all in java style. No wonder; this stuff *is* the domain of low-level stuff.

Line 1 as marked in the snippet I copy/pasted directly from the source of CHM (other than that remark) looks like a check **but it is not**. It **sets** `nextIndex` to transferIndex, *and then* checks if that value is below or equal to 0 in which case it enters the `else if`'s block.

So, here's the flow to get to `i >= n` triggering:

- This code loops once or a few times.
- It gets to that `if` check. `transferIndex` is a field. Another thread can change it (and given that we're talking about CHM, the code is obviously written to take into account that may have occurred).
- Because of this, `nextIndex` is now quite high. Higher than `n`. That's because another thread has been growing this map in the middle of this `transfer()` operation.
- Nevertheless, whilst `nextIndex` has been updated to the value of `nextTransfer`, the if fails. The next elseif (a CAS (Compare-and-set, a CPU primitive that is incredibly useful to write lock-free code that operates correctly in concurrent situations) op to ensure that in the few cycles we just spent going through these hoops, `transferIndex` is *still* the value we read a cycle or two ago), we have now 'claimed' the job and set `i` to `nextIndex - 1` **which could be higher than `n`!**.
- Then we get to the `i >= n` check you are asking about, and it could therefore indeed be true. I *think* the situation where that occurs is if, halfway through a transfer, some other thread has added some data to the CHM, but that's already been added to the post-transfer intended table so there is no need to act, thus, start the 'finishing' job which requires another CAS check and one more loop with `finishing = true` on.

NB: You may be thinking: Wait, `transferIndex` is being read but there is absolutely nothing establishing Happens-Before on transferIndex here, so whatever it reads, it's by definition a JMM violation and could be (and is in fact likely to be on modern CPUs) unaffected by other thread writes. But not so fast: Before a likely stale value of transferIndex is actually used, the code does a CAS check on `TRANSFERINDEX` (it's in the snippet I just pasted, in the final `else if`) and CAS checks also establish HB. It's not documented, because `Unsafe` isn't officially part of the spec, more or less. (It's sort of part of JVM spec and sort of not, bit of an oddball). For stale reads on this, the loop more or less just reloops.

As a general rule, to be truly fast in the face of likely concurrent operations, you want to be lock-free. To be lock-free, you need lots of CAS, and you use the CAS generally in a 'retry' style: You check current state, you act on current state, you then use CAS to confirm that the state you checked before is still the state, and if so, update and move on. If not, just.. do it again. Over and over until you 'win' ('win' = the CAS call succeeds because the thing you are CASing does have the expected value, expected = the thing it was when you started the calculation). Eventually you 'win'. Hence, it's best to read such code as having looped a few times, having done absolutely nothing, because CAS calls failed.

DBs work the same way: If you're familiar with MVCC style dbs and how you can use them to do lock-free ops with nevertheless the very highest concurrency guarantees (namely, `TransactionIsolationLevel.SERIALIBLE`, the 'toughest' level) - same principle at work. Retry-on-conflict - same thing happening here.

Comment: `That's because another thread has been growing this map in the middle of this transfer() operation.` No, I don't think it can due to: 1) Any new thread that tries to insert during a resize has **either** to [help with the transfer](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1023) or [acquire the lock on the bin and add the element](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1031).

Comment: In the middle of a transfer operation I don't think any thread can access the `nextTable` since `table` still points to the **old table**. [The switch only happens when a thread sets `finishing = true`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2467). So whenever `nextIndex` is updated, it does not use the length of the new table. **Correct me if I am wrong.**

Comment: As far the `transfer()` method goes : [`transferIndex` starts at `n`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2440), [`n` is always the **old** `table.length`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2427)

Comment: [`nextIndex` is set to `transferIndex`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2452) and is [only decremented](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0cc6300a02dd92b25d9072b8b3859dab583bbd/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2456). No other thread can increase transferIndex during the `transfer()`. **Correct me if I am wrong.**

Comment: Basically to grow the CHM during a `transfer` it can only add to the old table, IMO or help the transfer. **It cannot suddenly add to the new table during a transfer**. **Please correct me if I am wrong.**

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct.